# inner join on null condition : bug or feature?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is the test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO A (id, value) VALUES (1, 22);
INSERT INTO A (id, value) VALUES (2, 25);
INSERT INTO A (id, value) VALUES (3, 25);

CREATE TABLE B (
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    value bigint, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Important note: table B does not contain any row!!!

Test query:

```
select * from A  inner join B on (A.value=25 OR B.value=null);
```

Surprise: Empty result set fetched

If table B contain anything like:

```
INSERT INTO B (id, value) VALUES (3, 66);
```

Then the same query  will return 2 rows:

```
id  value  id  value  
--  -----  --  -----  
2   25     3   66     
3   25     3   66
```

This is a bug or a feature of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: An inner join where one table is empty will always return zero rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INNER JOIN by definition returns matching records only. If a table does not have any records, then there cannot be any metching record. This is a standard behaviour across all RDBMs. Use left or right join instead of inner if you want to return rows from a table regardless of matching rows from another.

```
select * from A  left join B on ... where A.value=25 ;
```

Moreover, anything=NULL comparison will always retur false, because NULL does not equal to anything, not even to another NULL value. If you want to test if a field has a value of NULL, then use fieldname IS NULL expression.

Comment: even 'select * from A inner join B on (true or B.value is null)' does not produce different results  - actually i have good reasons to NOT use LEFT join

Comment: You did not get my point: inner join looks for matching rows. If there is no row in a table, it won't return any rows, no matter what you put in the join condition.